# When would I use FBDEV vs DRM vs DSS?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, framebuffer, display-manager

I'm interested in developing a graphics driver. I see that Linux supports three methods for writing graphics to the display device

- FBDEV
- DRM
- DSS2

When would I use one versus the other?

Comment: Check this Embedded Linux Conference [link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DccR2-HOtA5g&ei=Wmr4U73JJpTq8AWS-4HQDA&usg=AFQjCNHHGQptsaJYY6lM92pB_68nbHDOcA&sig2=PHairBAkQlXabkrBYEVF1A&bvm=bv.73612305,d.dGc)

Comment: The current API seems to be DRM. It's the only direct graphics API wlroots supports.